# Why is the assigned value for this variable being lost?

Tags: c++, multithreading, variable-assignment

I'm hoping someone can see where I am going wrong here as it is doing my head in.

I have some code that loops through a number of airplane assets:

```
std::string UpdateService::getUpdate(std::string clientId) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    std::cout << "Getting asset repository for UpdateService\n"; 
    AssetRepository* assetRepository =
        AssetRepositoryFactory::getInstance().getAssetRepository(clientId);
    // get an update only if the asset has moved since last time

    std::vector<Airplane*> airplanes = (*assetRepository).getAllAirplanes();
    std::cout << "UpdateService airplanes repository size = "
              << airplanes.size() << "\n";

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < airplanes.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "UpdateService airplane is located at memory address 0x"
                  << std::hex << airplanes[i] << "\n";

        Airplane a = *(airplanes[i]);

        double x1 = a.getXSnapshot();
        double y1 = a.getYSnapshot();
        double z1 = a.getZSnapshot();
        std::string heading1 = a.getHeadingSnapshot();

        double x2 = a.updateXSnapshot();
        double y2 = a.updateYSnapshot();
        double z2 = a.updateZSnapshot();
        std::string heading2 = a.updateHeadingSnapshot();

        if (!approximatelyTheSame(x1,x2) ||
            !approximatelyTheSame(y1,y2) ||
            !approximatelyTheSame(z1,z2) ||
            heading1 != heading2 )
        {
            return "x: " + std::to_string(x2) +
                   " y: " + std::to_string(y2) + 
                   " z: " + std::to_string(z2) +
                   " heading: " + heading2;
        }

        return "";
    }

    return "";
}
```

It calls a couple of methods on `Airplane`:

```
double Airplane::getXSnapshot() {
    std::cout << "getXSnapshot()\n";
    std::cout << "m_x_snapshot is located at memory address 0x"
              << std::hex << &m_x_snapshot << "\n";
    std::cout << "m_x_snapshot is " << m_x_snapshot << "\n";

    return m_x_snapshot;
}

double Airplane::updateXSnapshot() {
    std::cout << "updateXSnapshot()\n";
    std::cout << "m_x_snapshot is " << m_x_snapshot << "\n";

    m_x_snapshot = (*m_airplane).getPosition()[0];

    std::cout << "m_x_snapshot is " << m_x_snapshot << "\n";

    return getXSnapshot();
}
```

The `getUpdate()` method is being called every second by a detached thread.

The problem I am having is that I assign a value to `m_x_snapshot` (`m_x_snapshot = (*m_airplane).getPosition()[0];`) but next time this method is called the value has reset to `0`.

Here is the output of this code:

```
Getting asset repository for UpdateService
m_airplanes.size() 1
m_airplanes[i] is located at memory address 0x00000000028A8230
UpdateService airplanes repository size = 1
UpdateService airplane is located at memory address 0x00000000028A8230
getXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is located at memory address 0x000000000324F398
m_x_snapshot is 0
updateXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is 0
m_x_snapshot is -7035
getXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is located at memory address 0x000000000324F398
m_x_snapshot is -7035
Diff 7035
The update is: x: -7035.000000 y: 652.188603 z: 51.730339 heading: 0
Getting asset repository for UpdateService
m_airplanes.size() 1
m_airplanes[i] is located at memory address 0x00000000028A8230
UpdateService airplanes repository size = 1
UpdateService airplane is located at memory address 0x00000000028A8230
getXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is located at memory address 0x000000000324F398
m_x_snapshot is 0
updateXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is 0
m_x_snapshot is -7035
getXSnapshot()
m_x_snapshot is located at memory address 0x000000000324F398
m_x_snapshot is -7035
Diff 7035
The update is: x: -7035.000000 y: 652.189632 z: 51.730314 heading: 0

... etc
```

As you can see, `m_x_snapshot` keeps reverting to `0` each time the method is called. I don't understand why, especially as it is at the same memory address?

Comment: The `for` loop in `getUpdate` only iterates once, due to the `return ""` that executes no matter what.

Comment: `Airplane a = *(airplanes[i]);` - This is calling a copy constructor.  Try `Airplane& a....` instead

Comment: @Ed Heal Thank you, this resolved the issue! I thought that dereferencing a pointer always referred back to the original. I've been caught out a couple of times by value vs reference semantics.

Comment: @Jonny Henly Thanks for that, I hadn't looked at the logic of that part yet as I hadn't got that far, but I have addressed it now.

Comment: It is not very elegant code though